# Given $\det(A+E)=0$, find $E$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

If $A$ is a known matrix, $E$ is a diagonal unknown matrix and

$$\det(A+E) = 0$$

one of the solutions for $E$ is $E = -a_i I$, where $a_i$ is an eigenvalue of $A$. How can find other solutions?

Comment: Are you sure there are finitely many solutions?

Comment: Have you looked at the $2\times2$ case?

Comment: Isn't it possible to make _any_ square matrix singular if we have the freedom to change one entry?